# Python, PIP & Conda, install package in global env

Tags: python, pip, package, conda, miniconda

I'm using Python for some projects. I want run some .py program with task scheduler Windows. The task scheduler is using the Global environnement (from Python) by default (which is fine for me).

I've tried to install packages in this Global environnement but there are always installed in Conda active environnement. I've tried to remove path env variable value which contains Conda but no success.
Powershell Sample where "(base)" is the Conda active env.
`(base) PS C:\Users\mayot> conda deactivate PS C:\Users\mayot> pip install webdriver_auto_update Requirement already satisfied: webdriver_auto_update in c:\users\mayot\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (0.1.0)`

I doesn't want to uninstall Conda, I've seen some tricks to run a .py programm with a specific env in task scheduler.

But what I want is simple : install the package where I want it to be installed.

Is it possible  ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It will be better if you reinstall the packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved this issue by uninstalling pip in Conda then run powershell in admin to reinstall it in global environnement. It worked...